# mostrar imagen mientras se procesa un formulario con jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo un formulario en una pagina html que es enviado a un archivo php. Mi idea es que una vez que se envíe el formulario y hasta que se carguen los datos en el php, se muestre una animación en pantalla.

El problema es que la animación no esta mostrando.

El archivo html es el siguiente

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>load</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <style>
        #cargando,#carga{
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form id=create method=POST action=archivo.php>
<input type=text name=nombre>
<input type="submit" value="Create" /> 
</form>
<div id='cargando' style='display:none'>
  <img src="load.gif" ><h3>Cargando página ...</h3>
</div>
<div id=cargado></div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#cargando').show();
    var url=$(this).attr("action");
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data, status)
        {
            $('#cargando').hide();
            $('#cargado').html(data); //content loads here

        },
        error: function (xhr, desc, err)
        {
            console.log("error");

        }
    });        

});
</script>
```

Y archivo.php es:

```
<?php
sleep(3);
echo $_POST['nombre'];
?>
```

Comment: Y si manualmente, por consola, pones `$('#cargando').show();`  sí se muestra?

Comment: PD: no veo que estés cerrando el tag `<form>` ni el tag `<h3>`. Puede que sea irrelevante, pero mejor probar con un HTML correcto.

Comment: ¿como probar directamente por consola, amenadiel?

Comment: F12 para abrir el panel devtools y ahí en la pestaña console podrás escribir ese comando. Funciona tanto en chrome como en firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el evento `beforeSend` de **ajax** el cual se ejecuta mientras los datos se procesan en el servidor:

Para más información sobre los eventos de ajax puedes visitar [Ajax Events](https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/)

**NOTA:** recuerda que el atributo `id` es un identificador único e irrepetible, por lo cual no debe repetirse entre 2 o mas elementos.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>load</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <style>
        #cargando,#carga{
            text-align: center;
        }

        #cargando{
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form id=create method=POST action=archivo.php>
<input type=text name=nombre>
<input type="submit" value="Create" /> 
<div id='cargando'>
  <img src="load.gif" ><h3>Cargando página ...</h3>
</div>
<div id=respuesta></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<script>
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();

    var url=$(this).attr("action");
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#cargando').show();
        },
        success: function (data, status)
        {
            $('#cargando').hide();
            $('#respuesta').html(data); //content loads here

        },
        error: function (xhr, desc, err)
        {
            console.log("error");

        }
    });        

});
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias, probé tu método pero sigue sin mostrar la imagen gif

Comment: Acabo de hacer un ajuste en mi respuesta de algo que no había visto inicialmete en tu código @user3333911 deberías revisar si la ruta de tu imagen es la correcta, el gif esta al mismo nivel que tu index ?

Comment: Si está en el mismo nivel. Aún no la muestra, disculpa

Comment: Ok, revisa con los cambios que hice y me cuentas :D

Comment: Funciono, gracias. Removí la línea `dataType: "JSON"`, ya que el código el formulario no la requiere. También tome en cuenta la version de jquery.js que estaba usando.

Comment: Genial, me alegra que pudieras resolverlo, teniendo en cuenta lo que dices tampoco necesitarías las líneas processData: false y contentType: false, saludos !!